# SQL Server 2014 : Transaction Logs error : “The transaction log for database 'ClientDB' is full due to 'XTP_CHECKPOINT'.”

Tags: sql-server-2014

SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2495.0 (X64)
    Mar 31 2015 09:47:37 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 
    Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Database Recovery Model : Full
Backup Type : Full

Performing simple `insert` transactions using `SQLBulkCopy` with `Batch size : 10000`

Database errors out after sometime as below:

> “The transaction log for database 'ClientDB' is full due to 'XTP_CHECKPOINT'.”

I am not able to perform any operations after this error message. Not able to shrink the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can see [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151225140751/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1028379/unable-to-clear-xtp-checkpoint-in-database-with-inmemory-table-usage)

They make: "... The XTP_CHECKPOINT cannot be removed from the log_reuse_wait unless a full db backup is done..."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I did not have replication but once I used Memory Optimized table as a test, database in Simple recovery mode, but my transaction logs weren't truncated.  Manual truncation, even right after a full backup, gave the error:

> Cannot shrink log file X because the logical log file located at the end of the file is in use.

A manual checkpoint failed:

> Msg 41315, Level 16, State 4, Line N
>   Checkpoint operation failed in database X.

A manual checkpoint only succeeded right after restarting the SQL Service, which would lead to a 4 hour In Recovery state because of my Multi Tb database size. I also tried to set the autogrowth to a specific size, but it all ended up doing the same: fill up the transaction logs until no space was left.

Finally, after days and nights trying and researching, I found the solution for my problem by installing the [Cumulative Update 3 for SQL Server 2014 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3090141)